# Lua: Quoted arguments passed as one in function

Tags: lua, pattern-matching

I'm attempting to simplify a script, and my attempts are failing. I'm making a function that will pass the given arguments and turn them into an indexed table, but I want to be able to pass quoted and non-quoted alike and have the function recognize that quoted arguments are considered one value while also respecting non-quoted arguments.

For example:

**makelist dog "brown mouse" cat tiger "colorful parrot"**

should return an indexed table like the following:

```
list_table = {"dog", "brown mouse", "cat", "tiger", "colorful parrot"}
```

The code I have works for quoted, but it's messing up on the non-quoted, and on top of that, adds the quoted arguments a second time. Here's what I have:

```
function makelist(str)
  require 'tprint'
  local list_table = {}
  for word in string.gmatch(str, '%b""') do
    table.insert(list_table, word)
  end
  for word in string.gmatch(str, '[^%p](%a+)[^%p]') do
    table.insert(list_table, word)
  end
  tprint(list_table)
end
```

I'm not understanding why the omission of quotes is being ignored, and also is chopping off the first letter. That is, this is the output I receive from tprint (a function that prints a table out, not relevant to the code):

```
makelist('dog "brown mouse" cat tiger "colorful parrot"')
1=""brown mouse""
2=""colorful parrot""
3="og"
4="rown"
5="mouse"
6="cat"
7="tiger"
8="olorful"
9="parrot"
```

As you can see, 'd', 'b', and 'c' are missing. What fixes do I need to make so that I can get the following output instead?

```
1="brown mouse"
2="colorful parrot"
3="dog"
4="cat"
5="tiger"
```

Or better yet, have them retain the same order they were dictated as arguments, if that's possible at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local function makelist(str)
  local t = {}
  for quoted, non_quoted in ('""'..str):gmatch'(%b"")([^"]*)' do
    table.insert(t, quoted ~= '""' and quoted:sub(2,-2) or nil)
    for word in non_quoted:gmatch'%S+' do
      table.insert(t, word)
    end
  end
  return t
end
```

Comment: What, not a comment this time?! ;)
This fails on unbalanced quotes; for example, try on `foo "unbalanced`, although one may argue that it's a virtue.

Comment: Haha, very much a virtue, I suppose! Awesome answer on this! And wow, I'm surprised, you actually answered instead of commented! Thanks, Egor!

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier to simply split on whitespaces and concatenate those elements that are inside quotes. Something like this may work (I added few more test cases):

```
function makelist(str)
  local params, quoted = {}, false
  for sep, word in str:gmatch("(%s*)(%S+)") do
    local word, oquote = word:gsub('^"', "") -- check opening quote
    local word, cquote = word:gsub('"$', "") -- check closing quote
    -- flip open/close quotes when inside quoted string
    if quoted then -- if already quoted, then concatenate
      params[#params] = params[#params]..sep..word
    else -- otherwise, add a new element to the list
      params[#params+1] = word
    end
    if quoted and word == "" then oquote, cquote = 0, oquote end
    quoted = (quoted or (oquote > 0)) and not (cquote > 0)
  end
  return params
end
local list = makelist([[
dog "brown mouse" cat tiger " colorful parrot " "quoted"
in"quoted "terminated by space " " space started" next "unbalanced
]])
for k, v in ipairs(list) do print(k, v) end
```

This prints the following list for me:

```
1   dog
2   brown mouse
3   cat
4   tiger
5    colorful parrot 
6   quoted
7   in"quoted
8   terminated by space 
9    space started
10  next
11  unbalanced
```

Comment: This fails on balanced quotes: `"terminated by space " next`

Comment: Great work on this! Egor's is a bit more simple, but man, I really wish I could give accepted answers to everyone. Instead, I hope everyone upvotes all these great answers! Thanks!

Comment: Should be fixed for strings started/ended with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

First thanks for your question, got me to learn the basics of Lua!

Second, so I think you went with your solution in a bit of misdirection. Looking at the question I just said why don't you split once by the quotes (") and than choose where you want to split by space.

This is what I came up with:

```
function makelist(str)
  local list_table = {}
  i=0
  in_quotes = 1
  if str:sub(0,1) == '"' then
     in_quotes = 0   
  end 
  for section in string.gmatch(str, '[^"]+') do
    i = i + 1
    if (i % 2) == in_quotes  then
      for word in string.gmatch(section, '[^ ]+') do    
         table.insert(list_table, word)
      end
    else
        table.insert(list_table, section)
    end
  end
  for key,value in pairs(list_table) do print(key,value) end
end
```

The result:

```
1   dog
2   brown mouse
3   cat
4   tiger
5   colorful parrot
```

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you learn something! Haha! Sometimes, as much as I know about Lua, I tend to make things difficult. I'm giving you a one up because your answer totally rocks, but the accepted answer accomplished the same thing before you did. But major props!